# Fit entire web page on the screen without using scroll bar in css

Tags: html, css

When I remove scroll bar using .body{ overflow-y;} in the CSS, I'm unable to see the entire page on the screen.

How do I fit the entire page on one screen without using scroll?

Comment: Use this, this might help you in responsive screen without a scroll : https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will fix your problem for all device

```
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 height:100vh;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```